# Copy only visible data entries in Excel, but something is going wrong, why?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to create a bit of VBA code that copies two columns of only visible data on all excel workbooks in a file.

For example, I might have this data visible (left number is column A, right is in column 2):

- 1  2
- 1  3
- 1  4
- 1  5

but the code I use merely copies 1 2 for this worksheet or, if there is a duplicate, as in

- 1 2
- 1 2
- 1 3

then it *only* copies the first duplicated values. I've posted the code I'm using below. What is going on?

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    FolderPath = "This is my folder path"

    NRow = 1

    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("C" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*You will need to use [Range.Copy Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) on your [xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213567(v=office.11).aspx)*

*Quick Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B100") _
                                                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Dim DestRange As Range
    Set DestRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")

        SourceRange.Copy DestRange

End Sub
```